# AutoMapper - Convert UTC to Timezone with ProjectTo (IQueryable)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, automapper

I was trying to figure out an way to convert all system dates (UTC) into user timezone using automapper. I am having an issue basically on using the method 'ProjectTo' and so far already tried the following non-working solutions

1. Create a map from DateTime to DateTime using a ITypeConverter
2. Using a custom implementation of IMemberValueResolver

Is there any solution for this or will be needed to convert **IQueryable** to **List** in first place?

**Update #1**

I want to execute the following line code

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc_date, some_timezone)
```

Thanks in advance.

TM

Comment: use [Value Transformers](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Value-transformers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you will need to convert `IQueryable` to a `List` in the first place. AutoMapper's `ProjectTo()` is a handy wrapper over LINQ's `Select()`. It converts the mapping configuration to an expression, which later on is translated to SQL query by an ORM like Entity Framework or Dapper. That's the reason why `ProjectTo()` supports only few of AutoMapper's [features](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options). Only those that can be translated to expressions will work. No ORM will know how to translate:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc_date, some_timezone)
```

Although there are SQL functions used for applying offset to datetime, such as T-SQL's `SWITCHOFFSET` (more in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/switchoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)), I doubt it will suit your needs, given that it is supposed to work with AutoMapper plugged-in.

I'd recommend first obtaining the data from the database and then applying the proper time zone offset. Such an approach will save you the trouble of time zone tweaking in database query, and you'll have direct access to user time zone, which I assume is not a fixed constant.